# Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular, local-storage

authentication.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

export class User {
constructor(
  public email: string,
  public password: string

 ) { }
 }

var users = [
 new User('admin@admin.com','adm9'),
 new User('user1@gmail.com','a23')
];
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
 constructor(
  private _router: Router){}
 logout() {
  localStorage.removeItem("user");
  this._router.navigate(['Login']);
}
login(user){
 var authenticatedUser = users.find(u => u.email === user.email);
  if (authenticatedUser){
   localStorage.setItem("user", authenticatedUser);
   this._router.navigate(['Home']);      
   return true;
 }
 return false;
}
 checkCredentials( ){
 if (localStorage.getItem("user") === null){
    this._router.navigate(['Login']);
  }
 } 
}
```

Error

> [at-loader] src\app\authentication\authentication.service.ts:32:36 
>       Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
localStorage.setItem("user", authenticatedUser);
```

Your `authenticatedUser` variable is an `object` but you can only set/get `string`s from local and session storage. So what you might do is something like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(authenticatedUser));
```

And when you need to get the item you should `JSON.parse()` it to an object again.

Comment: @Pravin happens to the best of us :-)

Comment: Question in my mind not related to above if you donot mind possible to give  answer   when I build application I got all code in dist folder I put in IIS in my .Net project then loading and execute in IIs like normal JavaScript engine then how it increase speed

Comment: @Pravin I'm not familiar with IIS and .Net :/

Comment: for any other suppose you want to use dist folder build application.  Is their any other engine you are using  for that or you use normal server like php xmapp or in java  like tomcat etc.

Comment: @Pravin I use nodejs's httpserver to bootstrap my apps. I've written a documentation about it: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/789/getting-started-with-angular-2/26878/getting-started-with-angular-2-with-node-js-expressjs-backend#t=201702150626539985015

Comment: I already read your link and also up vote it. but my question said after build application which server give me fast execution.

Comment: @Pravin I really don't know much about that topic :/